# Do lightweight transactions support delete statement with if exists?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I've read  that lightweight transactions just support update and insert statements with an "if" and "if exists" clause. Do they also support delete statement with "if exists" clause.

Eg : create table user(userid text,email text, primary key(email))

delete from user where userid='kris' if exists

Do lightweight transactions support the above delete statement?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the CQL DELETE statement does support the `IF EXISTS` clause.  From the [DELETE documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/delete_r.html):

> In Cassandra 2.0.7 and later, you can conditionally delete columns using IF or IF EXISTS. Deleting a column is similar to making an insert or update conditionally. Conditional deletions incur a non-negligible performance cost and should be used sparingly.

However, to Carlo's point, take note of that last sentence.  From a performance standpoint, the conditional delete is not free.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is: why do you need it? The `compare and set` is useful to handle race conditions -- e.g.: I don't want two users to register with same username. In this way a second attempt to register with same username will fail. But why would you delete a data if it exists when two delete operations are idempotent on your data? a delete has implicit `IF IT EXISTS` condition

Comment: hi Carlo;thanks for the response.  i have a coupon that needs to be allocated to one user. The first user who accesses the coupon and deletes the coupon would be able to redeem it.  So there could be 2 simultaneous requests to read and delete the coupon, which means i allotted the same coupon to 2 users.  If a request finds the coupon deleted, he needs to request for another valid coupon.